# "No results found" bug when selecting more results per page on the main page

Tags: bug, new-nav

I am using the new tab mode and when I want to display more results on a page and I'm inside a tag search, I get a message like this. This is obviously not correct as I'm only on one of the first few pages and the specific tag has more than 100 thousand questions.
I am using Safari 12603.1.30.0.34 on macOS 10.12.4.

[image: page with no results]

Comment: The [newnav] feature is no longer being maintained so reporting bugs is not very useful.  Otherwise a classic problem and reported many times before.  Caused by a query timeout, just try again.

Comment: @HansPassant I must have missed something, when did they stop supporting / maintaining the new-nav?